# Qual é a diferença entre fique à vontade e esteja à vontade?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Existe alguma diferença entre **fique à vontade** e **esteja à vontade**?

Ou as duas expressões têm o mesmo significado?

Comment: Eu diria que "fique à vontade" é muito mais frequente, pelo menos em pt-BR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nenhuma, que eu saiba.  Em alguns ambientes pode-se usar mais "fique à vontade", enquanto em outros a preferência caia sobre "esteja à vontade".  O significado é o mesmo e o grau de formalidade também.  Eu, pessoalmente, sem nenhuma referência para isso, acho que "esteja à vontade" soa mais apropriado como sendo uma resposta a um pedido.  Por exemplo:

- "Posso comer mais um pedaço de bolo?"  "Por favor, esteja à vontade (para fazê-lo).
- "Posso tirar os sapatos?"  "Esteja à vontade (para fazê-lo)".
- "Entre, fique à vontade".
- "Por favor, sentem-se e fiquem à vontade.

Answer (score 3):

No máximo, a diferença será a de frequência de uso em função de localidade, no máximo, sem grandes diferenças semânticas.

Além das variantes apresentadas, pode-se somar uma terceira variante "ponham-se à vontade".